# How can I get around Circular Dependency in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got 2 files which are importing each other

**File A**

```
import B from '...'

class A {
    
    ...

    public aOne(): number {
        return 1
    }

    public aTwo(): number {
        return B.bTwo() + 2
    }

    ...

 }
```

**File B**

```
import A from '...'

class B {
    
    ...

    public bOne(): number {
        return A.aOne() + 3 
    }

    public bTwo(): number {
        return 4
    }

    ...

 }
```

The issue is that I can't put one of the functions in a different place because they have to exist in their class but at the same time they are using each other and I get the circular dependency ERROR at build time.
Is there a way to navigate around this without re-creating one of the functions in a different file? Thank you

Comment: You haven't stated why you want to avoid doing the refactoring and I sense that your example is a trivialised version of the actual problem you face.

Comment: I don't think there's a way around what you are asking - you have to break the cyclic dependency and that can only happen if the code is refactored in some way - likely by moving code that is used by both classes to another common service class that they can both import.

Comment: This should work, your functions are not `static`, that's why your compilation fails.

Answer (score 1):

fixed version:

```
import { B } from './b';

export class A {    
    static aOne(): number {
        return 1
    }
    public aTwo(): number {
        return B.bTwo() + 2
    }
 }
```

```
import { A } from './a';

export class B {
    public bOne(): number {
        return A.aOne() + 3 
    }

    static bTwo(): number {
        return 4
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing it as `import A from '...'` use `import type`. It's going to be like the following:

```js
import type A from '...'
```

and

```js
import type B from '...'
```